# Starting ASP.NET Core MVC application throws Exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No files found matching exist in an asset

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

We got a new colleague this week, and we are trying to get our "big" application running in visual studio on his new PC.
All of the other developers have not had any issues starting this application, and we have been trying to figure what could be missing or blocking him from starting the application from a Visual Studio Debugger.

He is able to build the application, but as soon as the application starts it opens a browser and shows this error
[image: Error Message]

If he tries to login to a collogues PC it works, so we have ruled out permissions, and profile.

If one of the other developers logs onto his new PC, it does not work, so we think it is something like software or configuration, that is missing on this new PC.

We are sure that the code works, as it works fine one 5 other PCs.

A side note:
The project has rather recently (half a year ago) been upgraded from .Net framework 4.7.x to .Net 6. I guess all of the working laptops have had the application running in the old version at some point.

It is a ASP.NET CORE MVC Application.

Googling gives suggestions regarding Web-optimizer, wwwroot, bundle-something, nothing we have tried so far have changed the outcome of the error.

Comment: Hi Chen - Thanks for  you input.
You have any concrete property or configuration i should look at. 
We are getting cross eyed comparing settings :D 

But I believe you are right, something about paths does not seem right.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, a colleague figured it out.

Turns out that the Typescript builder does not transpile the typescript, unless something has changed.

So with no generated javascripts, Weboptimizer can't find the files it needs to work with.

So all we had to do is to change some typescript code (Not just putting in a whitespace somewhere). Then Typescript transpiler will register the code change, and build all the javascript code.